# Laravel eloquent, create collection based on Column value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an example table like the following:

```
| id | is_new | cate |
| 0  |   1    | [5]  |
| 1  |   1    | [5]  |
| 2  |   1    | [7]  |
| 3  |   1    | [6]  |
```

After I call the following function

```
   $product = Products::where('is_new', 1)->get();
```

the collection has the following data structure

```
Collection {#1284 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => Products {#1285 ▶}
    1 => Products {#1286 ▶}
    2 => Products {#1287 ▶}
    3 => Products {#1288 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I can also return a list of category id through:

```
    $category = Category::where('type', 2)->pluck('id')->all();
```

I wonder is there any good way to achieve following structure (or similar) based on cate. I can use brute force way to create it by looping through the $category then add to new collection manually, I think there is a better way to do it.

```
Collection {#1284 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    5 => array:2 [▼
         0 => Products {#1285 ▶}
         1 => Products {#1286 ▶}
         ]
    6 => Products {#1287 ▶}    or  6 => array:1 [ 0 => Products {#1287 ▶} ]
    7 => Products {#1288 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Solution Update based on answer:

```
$product->groupBy(function($item) {
        return $item['cate'][0]; //because the entry is a list
    });
```

Comment: What is cate and why is it in brackets? [5]

Comment: @EdwinKrause it could be a list sometimes, but you don't need to worry about it, just simply grab the first value. I know it looks weird for col entry to have a `list` that goes against the mysql itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at using something like [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) to group your categories together. It can be done on a database level (assuming you have [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)) with foreign keys. You'll also get a guarantee that what is returned is an array for each category, which will make things more consistent (you won't need to make a check for if it is an array or an instance of `Products`, then).

You might need to change your database layout if your categories are stored like arrays, but for this you should use an intermediary table - look at [many to many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: I will try `groupBy` (or something similar) out and provide feedback later. Thx you for concerning about the database structure but that one is just some special cases even though `cate` might sound a little bit misleading so who ever intent to make it actually knows what he was doing.